# How to print and save result of a Table in a text format in a loop?

Tags: matlab, text-files

```
result       'output1'   'output2' 
result1      [1.0000]    [0.0182]
counter      [     2]    [     0]
percentage   [     4]    [     7]
```

I have an output stored in a table (`T`), I want to print all my 200 loop results in just one text file. I already tried with writetable function and always have a problem, the output overwrite the previous output.

```
fid = fopen(filename,'w'); 
for i = 1:200
writetable(T,'finalresult.txt','Delimiter','\t','WriteRowNames',true);
end
fclose(fid);
```

the output should be like this:

```
result       'output1'   'output2' 
result1      [1.0000]    [0.0182]
counter      [     2]    [     0]
percentage   [     4]    [     7]


result       'output1'   'output2' 
result1      [0.0182]    [1.0000]
counter      [     3]    [     0]
percentage   [     4]    [     7]
```

and so on for all the outputs i = 200

Answer (score 1):

Per MATLAB's [documentation for `writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html), this is the default behavior.

> - If `filename` is the name of an existing text file, then `writetable` overwrites the file.

This gives you two options: create your own export routine or overload MATLAB's with the desired behavior. Let's look at the latter.

---

[image]

**Warning**: Modifying default MATLAB behavior can lead to unexpected results and errors. Take care to modify only *copies* of MATLAB's default files so you can revert MATLAB's state when you are finished.

---

Fortunately for us, the source code for `table` and its related methods are currently open so you can use [`open`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/open.html) to read them and understand their behavior. We see that `writetable` is a thin wrapper for the undocumented `table.write`, which parses the input arguments and makes the determination whether or not to write to a text file or to a spreadsheet. For the text case MATLAB calls the `writeTextFile` function (again, undocumented) which handles writing table data to a text file.

If you look at `line 25`, you will see that MATLAB opens the file for writing as follows:

```
% Open the file for writing
[fid,errmsg] = fopen(file,'Wt'); % text mode: CRLF -> LF
```

Per the documentation for [`fopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) this opens the file for writing (`'W'`), which will discard any existing contents. Saving a copy of `writeTextFile` and changing the `fopen` call to append data rather than overwrite it should give the desired behavior.

```
% Open the file for writing
fprintf('!!! Using overloaded writeTextFile D:\n%s\n', mfilename('fullpath'));
[fid,errmsg] = fopen(file,'At'); % text mode: CRLF -> LF
```

Per MATLAB's [Function Precedence Order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html), Private or Object functions take precedence over functions in MATLAB's path, so we need to place this modified file in the same location as the original. You can find this location this using [`which -all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html):

```
>> which writeTextFile -all
C:\excaza\writeTextFile.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\@tabular\writeTextFile.m  % tabular method
```

You should see your saved copy and MATLAB's built-in version. You should now **rename** the built-in function (e.g. `writeTextFile_builtin.m`) and copy your modified version of the file into the folder. Run a [`clear all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html) once to clear any memory cached version of the function.

We can now test to see if we've achieved the desired result:

```
filename = 'test.txt';

var1 = 1;
var2 = 2;

T1 = table(var1, 'RowNames', {'hi'});
T2 = table(var2, 'RowNames', {'hi'});

writetable(T1, filename)
writetable(T2, filename)
```

Which returns the following `test.txt`:

```
Row var1
hi  1
Row var2
hi  2
```

When you are done, be sure to revert the changes you made to the built-in.

Answer (score 0):

```
a1=0.1;
a2=0.2;

opt =fopen('test.txt','a');
```

`for i=1: size(t,1)`

```
j=1;
    if(i==1)
       s=strcat('\n','result','\t',t(i,j),'\t',t(i,j+1),'\n'); 
       s=s{1};
    end
    if (i==2)
        a1=t{i,j};
        a2=t{i,j+1};

   s=strcat('\n','result1','\t',num2str(a1),'\t',num2str(a2),'\n'); 
end

 if (i==3)
    a1=t{i,j};
    a2=t{i,j+1};

   s=strcat('\n','counter','\t',num2str(a1),'\t',num2str(a2),'\n'); 
end

    if (i==4)
    a1=t{i,j};
    a2=t{i,j+1};

   s=strcat('\n','counter1','\t',num2str(a1),'\t',num2str(a2),'\n'); 
end
if (i==5)
    a1=t{i,j};
    a2=t{i,j+1};

   s=strcat('\n','percentage','\t',num2str(s1),'\t',num2str(s1),'\n'); 
end



     fprintf(opt,s);
end
```

the output will be like this

```
result      output1     output2 

result1     1.0000       0.0182

counter       1          1

counter1      0          0

percentage    0          0
```

I solved it without doing any function modification. @Brian thank you for the answer, and clear explanation.